# Как установить в pycharm библиотеку PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm, pip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`pip install --upgrade pip` - пробовала

Comment: в thonny все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `PyCharm` вы можете установить библиотеку, пользуясь встроенным средством:

```
File > Settings > Project: *project_name* > Project Interpreter
```

Там можно настроить путь к вашему `Python` и установить библиотеку из списка

Answer (score 1):

1) Активируйте виртуальное окружение (из папки `vk`):

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

2) Установите `Pillow`:

```
pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

---

Ошибка в том, что Вы не активировали виртуальное окружение, поэтому установили `Pillow` в папку `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages`.

Cкрипт ищет модуль в папке `C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\vk\venv\Lib\site-packages`, следовательно его нужно туда установить, активировав окружение.

Answer (score -1):

Библиотека Pillow установлена?

```
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

Comment: "Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (6.0.0)" - Да установлена

Comment: pip install --upgrade wheel
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.33.4

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: Pillow in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (6.1.0)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/vk/venv/Scripts/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    import Pillow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score -1):

Если у вас винда, то можно зайти с помощью командной строки в путь, где лежит python.exe и сделать

```
python.exe -m pip install <пакет>
```

и всё должно подтянуться, это на случай, если вариант с установкой прямо из pycharm не нравится